# injection function value to global variable failure

Tags: c++, dll

well, I have injected c++ dll in c# and passed int value in however when Inject called
value of y is assigned in x, afterwards in the end of function it gets back to its value 0;
"anotherFunction" is called by event handler of Inject.
I really don't understand the what am I missing there, hope it worth to ask thanks.

```
int x =0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Inject(int y)
{
    x = y;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void OnInject()
{        
   anotherFunction();
}


void anotherFunction()
{
  printf("%i",x);
}
// value is 0
```

Comment: Are you printing the value of `x` from the same program that called `Inject` or from a different program?

Comment: How are you calling anotherFunction()? Please show your C# code.

Comment: anotherFunction() called from dll injected, there an OnInject fucntion